# Data Privacy in Workbench

Tags: workbench, gdpr

We are using Workbench for data manipulation. Right now I'm checking the tool in terms of data privacy but unfortunately there is no reals statement from Workbench. So my question is:

Does Workbench stores data at any time?

Answer (score 5):

You can audit the source code of Workbench in its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench).

Workbench isn't an official product of Salesforce:

> Workbench is NOT a supported product of or supported by salesforce.com, inc

and doesn't fall under any compliance regimes of the parent company.

With the disclaimer that I am not a Workbench contributor or a PHP expert, a quick look at its source shows that it uses Redis for queueing [asynchronous jobs run on the server](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/tree/main/workbench/async),  which does mean the server may store some data in a transitory way. That would include your session id and org details, and possibly [data returned from some types of operation you execute](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/blob/main/workbench/async/QueryFutureTask.php#L65). It does not persist these data to a long-lived database, however.

If you need compliance, you'll likely be in a better position by using a product that runs 100% locally, hosting your own Workbench instance, or purchasing a commercial solution that offers you GDPR compliance.

Comment: I was also typing an answer, and noted that PHP stores file uploads in a temp folder, so by definition, some data is persisted to ephemeral storage while handling some data and metadata types.